# TypeMatrix keyboard connector type

Tags: connector, debugging

I'm trying to investigate problem in my type matrix keyboard and I have two questions [image: type matrix mainboard]

1. how is called that connector (what type is it) on the right, it has around 25 pins +/- 2 pins?
2. Is it possible to read what is inside that chip on the left or debug that somehow?

Br,
bioky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connector is commonly called a flat-flex ribbon connector (FFC). Here is the section on Digikey for them: [Digikey Section](http://www.digikey.ca/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/ffc-fpc-flat-flexible-connectors/1442849)

Getting that sort of cover material off of devices can be challenging. You might want to try searching the internet to see if anyone has done it first, or knows what is on that particular board (search by part number). Otherwise you're going to have to try decapsulating it which can get tricky. Depending on the material it involve anything from requiring heat, to acid.